# Is there a way how to run registerContentScripts immediately?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I am trying to insert content script on every page dynamically.
I use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts for that.

```
chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts([{
        js: ['content.bundle.js'],
        matches: ['<all_urls>'],
        id: 'content-bundle'
      }])
```

It is working only when I reload tab or when open new one. I need that it runs immediately too. chrome.scripting.executeScript is not suitable for me, as it works only for selected tabs(chrome.tabs.query), not for all tabs(newly created). Moreover chrome.scripting.executeScript is not possible to unregister.

How do I make the registerContentScripts run immediately?

Comment: The only way is to use **both** registerContentScripts and executeScripts. There's no other way.

Comment: Yes I tried run at. It doesn`t change anything.